# JWT cookie not set after login

Tags: symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

Given following firewall setup:

```yaml
        api:
            provider: app_user_provider
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            entry_point: jwt
            login_throttling:
                max_attempts: 5
                interval: '10 minute'
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login/check
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
            jwt: ~
            refresh_jwt:
                check_path: /api/token/refresh
            logout:
                path: api_token_invalidate
```

With following jwt bundle configuration:

```yaml
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
    token_ttl: '%env(int:JWT_TTL)%'
    user_identity_field: email
    
    # token extraction settings
    token_extractors:
        authorization_header:
            enabled: true
        cookie:
            enabled: true
            name: '%env(JWT_NAME)%'
    
    set_cookies:
        '%env(JWT_NAME)%': ~
        
    remove_token_from_body_when_cookies_used: false
```

I can use the `/api/login/check` endpoint to login just fine and the jwt cookie is set as expected.

However, I need to programatically login a user after registration, so I am using `Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security::login` to login, as follows:

```php
$this->security->login($user, 'json_login', 'api');
```

which logs me in just fine, but the jwt cookie is not set.

Any idea why and what I need to do to make sure the jwt cookie it is set in this case as well?

Answer (score 1):

Try to create the token programmatically following this guide: https://symfony.com/bundles/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/current/7-manual-token-creation.html

Look at this example:

```
public function fooAction(UserInterface $user)
{
    $authenticationSuccessHandler = $this->container->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success');

    return $authenticationSuccessHandler->handleAuthenticationSuccess($user);
}
```

This method should set also the cookie accordingly to the provided configuration.

If this doesn't work, you could create a listener for the AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS event and create the cookie manually (https://symfony.com/bundles/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/current/2-data-customization.html).

An example:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Event\AuthenticationSuccessEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class AuthenticationSuccessListener {
    public function onAuthenticationSuccessResponse(AuthenticationSuccessEvent $event)
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $user = $event->getUser();

        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            return;
        }

        // ...

        $event->setData($data);
    
        $response->headers->setCookie(Cookie::create('YOUR_ENV_COOKIE_NAME', $data['token']));
        
    }
}
```

Here's the documentation to create a cookie: [https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#:~:text=response%2D%3Esend()%3B-,Setting%20Cookies,-The%20response%20cookies](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#:%7E:text=response%2D%3Esend()%3B-,Setting%20Cookies,-The%20response%20cookies)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware I could do this programatically, I was just hoping the `login` method could do it automatically for me.